# Bootstrap function with floats

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float, media-queries

I have some statements regarding the entire system, which, if someone could verify them helps me to understand Bootstrap much better:

**Statement 1:** With increasing device size, Bootstrap will start floating columns based on the class prefix, eg col-md, that is used. Everything that is below this prefix is not floated and will stack, unless it is further defined with sm or xs as well.

**Statement 2:**  If size < col-md and float is applied to only one element in the grid, everything will wrap around it, which results in a mess, since all other elements are not floated. The parent element will need to be clearfixed individually.

I hope this is clear and goes into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have looked at this? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid under grid options you see the column width maybe this can help you?